# Running Scheduled Tasks with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

I started coding in Powershell today and noticed that when I ran scheduled tasks via powershell, it wouldn't register as running in the Task Scheduler(`Run "Taskschd.msc"`). The code I'm using is here:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\TaskPathHere\" | Start-ScheduledTask
```

When I run a task manually(`right-mouse click>Run`), the status changes from `Ready` to `Running`. This isn't the case when ran from Powershell.

**Question:**
Is there some additional parameter I need to pass to change the Status, or is this intentional behavior? If it is intentional, why?

Comment: Try to press refresh in Task Scheduler GUI after starting task in PowerShell.

Comment: @PetSerAI Still nothing. I can't even track the status through saving task to a variable and checking the State. Ex: $task.State

Comment: Are you sure, that the task not got completed to the time you press refresh, check last run time of the task?

Comment: @PetSerAI Positive. The task generates files in a specific location then moves them to an archived location. I can view the process as it happens. It takes ~4mins.

Comment: If task's main process create child process and finish, the task will be considered completed while child process still running. Are you sure it is not the case?

Comment: @PetSerAI That's probably the case. I was just looking for some way to keep track of the child process and wait for it's completion.

Comment: Depending on how you're doing it (robocopy?) is it worth ensuring that the script doesn't end until all actions are complete? (`Start-Process [...] -Wait`)

Comment: Check if you have properly specified the path. It has backslashes natively, so it could get accidentally escaped somewhere.