# Checking Scheduled Tasks for completion with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

I have a couple of scheduled tasks within the Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2012. I'm running these tasks through PowerShell with

```psh
$Tasks = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\PathHere\"
Foreach($task in $Tasks)
{
    Start-ScheduledTask | Where {$_.TaskName -notlike 'someExample'}
}
```

I'm looking for a way to check to see when the task is completed. I figured that I could just check the status on the tasks in `$Tasks`, but when wrote sample code to duplicate the issue...

```psh
$task = Get-ScheduledTask someTask -TaskPath "\PathHere\"
Write-Host "State: $($task.State)"
Start-ScheduledTask $task.TaskName -TaskPath "\PathHere\"
Write-Host "State: $($task.State)"
```

I expected this code to result in `Ready`, then `Running`, but it ended up printing `Ready`, `Ready`.

I also noticed that the status in the Task Scheduler was not changing when the task was in process, as it would if one does a right mouse click and selects run. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480877/running-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell) for more details.

I'm looking for any way to check to see if the Task is completed in PowerShell.

I was looking around for some form of callback in PowerShell, but wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIM objects does not update themselves automatically. You have to refresh them manually:

```
$task=$task|Get-CimInstance
```

Now you can recheck value of `State` property.